# Django Template To Display Nested List Of Years And Dates

Tags: django, date, nested, templating

I have in my view the following code...

```
dates = Article.objects.dates('date', 'month').order_by('-date')
```

Which generates the following list of dates...

```
[
    datetime.date(2016, 3, 1), datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), 
    datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), datetime.date(2015, 2, 1), 
    datetime.date(2015, 2, 1), datetime.date(2015, 1, 1),
    datetime.date(2015, 1, 1)
]
```

I now need to create a nested list using the following markup...

```
        <ul class="news-selector">
            <li><a href="todo">Year</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="todo">Month</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I am struggling with using 'changeif' or 'regroup' does anyone know how to manage this using the django templating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would give you the list

```
<ul class="news-selector">
  {% for y in dates %}
    {% ifchanged y.year %}
      <li><a href="todo">{{y|date:'Y'}}</a>
        <ul>
          {% for m in dates %}
            {% if m|date:'Y' == y|date:'Y' %}
              <li><a href="todo">{{ m|date:'M' }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {% endifchanged %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it now its in the {% if m|date:'Y' == y|date:'Y' %} line, I have managed to do it with less loops by preparing the data in the view a bit better.

```
date_list = Article.objects.dates('date', 'month', order='DESC')

dates = []
for date in date_list:
    dates.append({
        'year': str(date.year).rjust(4, '0'),
        'month': str(date.month).rjust(2, '0'),
        'month_name': date.strftime("%B")
    })
```

And in the template...

```
            {% regroup dates by year as year_dates %}

            <ul class="news-selector">
            {% for year in year_dates %}
                <li><a href="todo">{{year.grouper}}</a>
                    <ul>
                    {% for month in year.list %}
                        <li><a href="{% url 'news_filter' month.year month.month %}">{{month.month_name}}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
```

Seems to work, but probably can be improved upon.